# Using slideToggle() for closest or next div

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

Okay, redoing the question to a much simpler one.

Here's my HTML code.

```
<p>
<span id="tripTitle">Trip #1</span>&nbsp;
    <span class="expandicon" style="display:none;">
        <span class="flip">
        <img class="expand" src="img/expand1.png" />
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="shrinkicon">
        <span class="flip">
        <img class="shrink" src="img/shrink1.png" />
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
<div class="panel"><table id="table" width="100%">
some text here.
</div>
```

and here's the Java:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

The HTML will repeat 10 times in a single page or for every Trip created. The javascript code will toggle all div's with the class "panel". Question is: Is there a way so the only div that toggles is the one closest or next to the image with the class "flip" clicked?

By the way, here's a jsfiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/LyUnB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).parent().nextAll(".panel:eq(0)").slideToggle("slow");
```

`.panel` is a sibling of the parentNode of `.flip`

Comment: This absolutely works. But there seems to be some unsmoothness to the sliding of the table in the end. Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: I cannot give an answer without seeing your CSS

Comment: I don't really have much CSS except for font editing, just using classes for jQuery. Here, you can see my example at http://jsfiddle.net/LyUnB/

Comment: Got it. Just add another .parent(). $(this).parent().parent().nextAll(".panel:eq(0)").slideToggle("slow"); Thanks, @DR.Molle.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
     });
});
```

You are having Expand, Shrink button inside an other span, so when you check `.next()` in jQuery it dont find `'.panel'`, we go one step back by using `parent()` and then `.next()` will take us to `'.panel'` div

Thank you

Comment: It only toggles when the minimize button is showing; does nothing when i click maximize but change the image to minimize. Also, if I wrap the first three lines of the HTML that I posted with <p></p>, the toggle seems ineffective. Newbie here.

Comment: Yes, you have to take care of the structure of html, if you change html layout you have to change the JS too. About your other question of Showing the image, you can simply change the img src of the child image inside the flip span.

Comment: Is there one more level higher than parent? That is if I wrap the Title text and the image in <p></p>. Thanks @aamir.

Comment: you can use `$(this).parent().parent().parent()...` nth time

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".shrinkicon").next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Works fine on my system. Here's working example with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kp5a6/)

Comment: This does nothing, my friend.

Comment: @MikeSanchez, it works fine here. I've updated my answer with the working example link.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. Any HTML code to stop the title Table 2 from moving beside Table 1 after the toggle? I tried <br /> but it snaps before the slide finishes. Wrapped Title 1 and the image in <p></p> but that prevents the topics from toggling.